# What is the best way to initialise a dynamic JTable with custom renderers?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, initialization, tablecellrenderer

Currently I initialise my `JTable` in my `JPanel` like so:

```
private ArrayData data;
private JTable table;
private CustomTableModel model;

public ExtendedJPanel() {
    data = ArrayData.getData();

    model = new CustomTableModel(data);
    table = new JTable(model);

    TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    col.setCellRenderer(new Column0Renderer());
    col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    col.setCellRenderer(new Column1Renderer());

    // do some other stuff
}
```

When I want to modify all the values in the `JTable`

I interact with the `TableModel` directly by creating a new `Object[][]` array and calling `fireTableCellUpdated(row, column)` for all my cells.

My problem is that, at some point in my program, my `JTable` loses its custom renderers.

I've been told that this is because it is updating the `TableColumnModel`.

What's the best way to initialise a `JTable` such that the `CellRenderers` stay 
constant throughout the life of the `JTable`?

Answer (score 2):

> When I want to modify all the values in the table, I interact with the TableModel directly by creating a new Object[][] array and calling fireTableCellUpdated(row, column) for all my cells.

No, you should never call `fireTableCellUpdated(...)` directly. That is the job of the TableModel. Changes to the data should be done via the TableModel, not an external data storage like the Array.

If you want to change the data in the table then use the setValueAt(...) method of the TableModel.

You can always add a `clear(...)` method to your custom TableModel that resets the internal data.

> What's the best way to initialise a JTable such that the CellRenderers stay constant throughout the life of the JTable?

Depends on what you mean by initialize. When using the DefaultTableModel you can just use:

```
model.setRowCount(0);
```

and all the data is removed.

Then you can use the `addRows(...)` method to dynamically add data.

> My problem is that, at some point in my program, my JTable loses its custom renderers. I've been told that this is because it is updating the TableColumnModel.

Yes, whenever you do something like:

```
table.setModel(...);
```

a new TableColumnModel is created and you lose your custom renders. Using my suggestion above this will not be a problem, because you haven't changed the "structure" of the table (just removed the data), so there is no need to recreate the TableColumnModel.

Comment: I never actually call `table.setModel(...);` What I have is a custom method in the `TableModel` which swaps out the old `Object[][]` for the new `Object[][]`. So my TableModel stays constant. 

My main concern is the ColumnModel changing and losing my renderers. I'm not sure why that is since I don't _think_ I revalidate the table at any point.

Comment: `I never actually call table.setModel(...);` well I said "something like". If you aren't doing this then your swapping code in invoking a fireXXX() method which is causing the TableColumnModel to be recreated. The code in you custom TableModel is causing the problem.

Comment: So would I be safe in assuming that calling `fire...()` methods is generally unsafe for manual calling?

Comment: No they are not unsafe, they are necessary in order for the table to repaint itself when changes are made. But they should only be invoked by the TableModel since only the table model should know when data changes. The problem is that your TableModel code is invoking the wrong fireXXX() method. Since you have posted your custom TableModel we can't guess what you are doing. If you want people to help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when you post a question.